# Jmeter issue - How to record Auto login of application via jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm pretty new to jMeter but knows the basics pretty well.
I got a task to perform a loading test which goes like that:

- User navigate to HomePage of responsive application.
- User perform login via **Google account**.
- User play few games (Its like a trivia game)
- User reach to the last screen.

I have managed to record the whole login and user scenarios using BlazeMeter addon.
When i run the test the few first request are OK, but the one related to google API login is getting error 400.

How can i overcome this?
Do i need to generate an auth token? if so, how to do it?
I'm really hopeless. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

> User perform login via Google account

According to [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) you either need to implement the OAuth sign-in process using JMeter or if you have valid [Authorization Bearer token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) you can just add it using JMeter's [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as this sign-up using a Google Account is not something you need to test, you must focus solely on your application functionality.

In case if you don't have token(s) and have to go via the OAuth flow check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for possible solutions.